# How to convert pdf to multiple swf files

Tags: printing, pdf, swf

I'm new to Ubuntu

How do I convert a .pdf file to a number of .swf files (the number of .swf files depends on the number of pages in the .pdf file).

Thanks in advance

Comment: have a look at: http://wiki.swftools.org/wiki/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

You can use the convert script from ImageMagick. If ImageMagick is not installed  then open a terminal and install it using

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then to convert a pdf file to swf issue:

```
convert filename.pdf filename.swf
```